# How do I become the Puppet Master?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I'm trying to get the achievement [Puppet Master](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/puppet-master) for the Witch Doctor:
[image: Puppet Master: Have 7 pets and/or followers at the same time.]

I've got the following:

- 4 [Zombie Dogs](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/summon-zombie-dogs) (requires the [Zombie Handler](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/passive/zombie-handler) passive skill)
- [Gargantuan](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/gargantuan)
- Fetish from [Big Bad Voodoo](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/big-bad-voodoo)
- My [Templar](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/follower/templar/) Follower

This seems like it should be enough, right?  Furthermore, the pets I've got correspond to the ones in the achievement's picture.  However, the achievement has not yet popped.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try Corpse Spiders? Zombie Charger? I don't think the Templar counts.

Comment: Yeah, this is a weird one.  They specifically show the Voodoo Fetish, and the achievement specifically mentions "followers" - which the templar is, from my understanding.  It's a mystery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Big Bad Voodoo](http://www.diablowiki.net/Big_Bad_Voodoo) doesn't really count as a pet,it is more like AOE ward.

On lvl 30 you will get [fetish army](http://www.diablowiki.net/Fetish_Army) and it makes an easy achievement.

Also additional followers you get from quests like Tyrael,Leah... don't count.But main followers templar,enchantress and scoundrel do.

Answer (score 3):

The [fetish army](http://www.diablowiki.net/Fetish_Army) is your best bet. I'm fairly certain the Big Bad Voodoo fetish doesn't count, but the six dagger wielding fetishes plus your zombie dogs and gargantuan will get the achievement.

That's how I got it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that either the Templar doesn't count due to being a follower but not a class specific one, or that the Fetish doesn't count, probably because of a glitch. Try bringing out the Zombie Charger as well, maybe with Wave of Zombies if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the achievement with dogs, passive dog bonus and Gargantuan.